# Connecting to AppNexus API through ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, api

I have to connect with AppNexus API and retrieve data related to active publishers information.
How to connect with API to use the services provided by AppNexus. Can anyone provide a sample snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use appnexusapi gem to get the details without any hesitation.

To use this gem just add the gem at Gemfile and bundle as follows:

```
   gem 'appnexusapi'
```

For establish connection use the connection service

```
            def establish_connection 
                @connect = AppnexusApi::Connection.new({'uri' => 'http://api.appnexus.com/', 'username'=>'xxxxx','password' => 'xxxxxx'})
                @key     = @connect.login
            end
```

From that onwards you just use the get and post methods provided by this gem as follows

```
dat =@connect.get('http://api.appnexus.com/publisher?stats=true&state=active&interval=yesterday')
```

The above call is mainly useful to get active publishers

Comment: Thanks it meets my requirement

Answer (score 2):

They are just basic REST calls

authenticate

```
token = RestClient.post("http://your.appnexus.url/auth", 
  { 'auth' => {'username' => 'username', 'password' => 'password'} }.to_json, 
    :content_type => :json, :accept => :json)
```

service call

```
RestClient.get("http://your.appnexus.url/creative?advertiser_id=1&campaign_id=2&start_element=100&num_elements=100", 
  :content_type => :json, :accept => :json, :authorization => token)
```

This will return a hash with

```
{'creatives' => [your creatives], 'count' => 1000, 'num_elements' => 100, 'start_element' => 100}
```